# Query cassandra table from spark without using case classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, bigdata, nosql

I am using [datastax's connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) for connecting to cassandra.

Below is the code that I used,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val conf=new SparkConf(true)
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","127.0.0.1")
.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","the_username")           
.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","the_password")

val sc=new SparkContext("local","the_keyspace",conf)
val table_1 = sc.cassandraTable("the_keyspace","table_1")
val table_2 = sc.cassandraTable("the_keyspace","table_2")
```

Now, the way to expose this table as an RDD is by using a case class as a placeholder as below

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
sc.cassandraTable[Person](“test”, “persons”).registerAsTable(“persons”)
```

This works fine, but I have around 50+ columns in each table and it is a real pain to type them out in a case class and also identifying their types.

Is there a way to overcome this ? I am used to getting the csv file as a table using databricks-csv and I can register them as tables and run queries on them without using a case class placeholder, is there something similar for my use case here.

If there are none, it would be helpful if there are some generators that I can use to auto-generate these case classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create data frame directly:

```
val df = sqlContext
   .read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
   .options(Map("keyspace" -> "test", "table" -> "persons"))
   .load()
```

Comment: This is how you should be making all data frames :) No need to go through "registerAsTable" unless you have an RDD in the first place.

Comment: That's pretty neat.But how do I query this using Spark SQL, I tried registering this as a temp table using `df.registerTempTable` but it throws an error such as method not found.I know data frame API is faster, but I am doing proof of concept now with a lot of query patterns and I it would be useful if I can use SQL queries.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Which version of Spark / Connector do you use?

Comment: I am using 1.4.1 (Spark), 1.5.0 M1 (connector) , there are some other issues that I am facing such as not able do regular dataframe API functions such as `df.show`,let me get back on that.But that is how you do it right, to be able to run spark sql do df.registerTempTable ?

Comment: I use Cassandra 2.1.8 / Spark 1.4.1 / Connector [1.4.0-M3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/1.4.0-M3). As far as I can tell everything works just fine, at least on some toy data.

Comment: It was a setup problem from my end.Your code worked, thanks for the help :)